# Drupal view Image link to a page of same content type in views

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a content type called Realisation. 
**Realisation** 
Title  
Body  
Thumb Image

I create a Block View and a Page View 
**Page View**  
I display only Title, and the Body.
I setup the path url parameter as "/MyRealisation"

**In the block view** 
 I only show a list of Thumb Image.
I link my Thumb Image with the content.

When I click on my image, it's not using my custom Page View.
I Notice that the path is wrong. It show node/62 instead of /MyRealisation/node/62

Is there any reason ?.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want have url each nodes like so site.com/MyRealisation/node/62

You need install module [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto)

Next you need go *to admin/config/search/path/patterns* and from this page write your templates for any node types